# Get full url from tornado web patterns

Tags: python, regex, url, tornado

I use python Tornado, and I want extract from this URL:

http://myserver.com/v1/files_get/app/path/for/you/myfile.txt

this value:

```
app
```

and the rest of path (path):

```
/path/for/you/myfile.txt
```

I use this REGEXP for it into Tornado:

```
tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/v1/files_get/(?P<root>[^\/]+)/?(?P<path>[^\/]+)?/?", files_get),
])
```

I don't know if it is possible, because my regexp only get only just level of path.

¿What should be the correct regex for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
r'/v1/files_get/(?P<root>[^/]+)(?P<path>/.*)?'
```

`/` is not magic, and you're not using it as a delimiter (as you would in Perl or Ruby), so it does not need to be escaped.

Since you want to capture everything after <root>, if it exists, you can make that whole group optional.